# How to find total enrolled students and total number of students who attempted an assignment in Moodle?

Tags: mysql, moodle

We are conducting an assignment based exam and want to find how many students attempted the assignment out of total enrolled students.

```
subject Name, total_enrolled, total_attempted

ABC, 12, 8
```

I have tried and can calculate the `total_attempted` and `total_enrolled` in separate queries, but do not know how to combine them in one.

Here is my attempt to calculate the `total_attempts`.

```
SELECT c.fullname, COUNT(c.fullname)  
FROM {assign_submission} AS a, {course} AS c, {assign} AS aa
WHERE a.assignment = aa.id 
  AND c.id = aa.course 
  AND a.userid > 60 
  AND a.status IN ('draft', 'submitted')
  AND FROM_UNIXTIME(a.timemodified) BETWEEN '2020-06-24 12:00:00' AND '2020-06-26 12:00:00'
GROUP BY c.fullname
ORDER BY c.fullname
```

And the query for the `total_enrolled` students of the above subjects is

```
SELECT c.fullname, COUNT(c.fullname)
FROM {user} AS u, {course} AS c, {enrol} AS e, {user_enrolments} AS ue
WHERE u.id = ue.userid 
  AND e.id = ue.enrolid
  AND e.courseid = c.id 
  AND c.id IN (SELECT c.id 
               FROM {assign_submission} AS a, {course} AS c, {assign} AS aa 
               WHERE a.assignment = aa.id 
                 AND c.id = aa.course 
                 AND a.status IN ( 'draft', 'submitted')
                 AND c.fullname <> 'Faculty Information and announcement'
                 AND FROM_UNIXTIME(a.timemodified) Between '2020-06-24 12:00:00' and '2020-06-26 12:00:00')
GROUP BY c.fullname
ORDER BY c.fullname
```

Is it possible in one query?

This is my first attempt with moodle and mySQL, so any improvements in these queries will also be appreciated.

Comment: @Strawberry, Thank you. If anybody is having Moodle, he can use these queries. But I will need more time to regenerate these reproducible examples. Working on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Using a sum on the submissioncount simply because it needs to be included in the group by */
SELECT c.id AS courseid, c.fullname AS coursename, COUNT(*) AS totalenrolled, SUM(a.submissioncount) AS submissioncount
FROM mdl_course c
JOIN (
    /* A user can be enrolled more than once on a course so only count distinct users */
    SELECT DISTINCT e.courseid, ue.userid
    FROM mdl_enrol e
    JOIN mdl_user_enrolments ue ON ue.enrolid = e.id
) ue ON ue.courseid = c.id
JOIN (
    /* Use a join on the submission count */
    SELECT a.course AS courseid, COUNT(*) AS submissioncount
    FROM mdl_assign a
    JOIN mdl_assign_submission s ON s.assignment = a.id
        AND s.status IN ('draft', 'submitted')                 
        AND FROM_UNIXTIME(s.timemodified) BETWEEN '2020-06-24 12:00:00' and '2020-06-26 12:00:00'
    GROUP BY a.course
) a ON a.courseid = c.id
WHERE c.fullname <> 'Faculty Information and announcement'
/* Always group by the id because the fullname isn't unique */
GROUP BY c.id, c.fullname
ORDER BY c.fullname, c.id
```

Comment: England Thank you but why I am getting more submission counts that enrolled students? It should not be more than enrolled students as we are counting only submitted or saved as a draft assignment

Comment: we only allowed one submission per student for each assignment